# clang-format for old-style K&R function definitions

Tags: c, clang-format

Working on a very old codebase using pre-ANSI C conventions, I'd like `clang-format` to produce an output like

```c
int
main(argc, argv)
int argc;
char *argv[];
{
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, it insists on formatting this as

```c
int main(argc, argv) int argc;
char *argv[];
{
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to make it put each declaration on its own line?

Comment: Is there a reason not to convert to prototyped definitions at the same time as you're reformatting the code?

Comment: Yes: Patches likely to not be accepted and I guess it may no longer compile on some ancient platform/compiler combinations.

Comment: (Potentially solved in https://reviews.llvm.org/D107961#2943445)